# Express.js: how to make app.get('/[:userId]i'..) in req.param?

Tags: regex, node.js, routes, get, express

I m using nodejs 0.8.21 and express 3.1.0

I need to read `userId` from url like `http://mysite.com/39i`. It means `userId=39`.
How to do? Thank you.
Sample:

```
app.get('/:userId_i', function(req, res) { });
app.param('userId', function(req, res, next, id){ });
```

Comment: Reference: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have a numerical id followed by an `i` and you want the id coming back as just the numerical.

```
app.get("/:id([0-9]+)i", function (req, res) {...});
```

This will match a numeric followed by an `i` and will give you just the numeric in `req.params.id`.

Example:

```
curl -XGET localhost:8080/124i
```

Gives me the following in `req.params`

```
[ 'id': 124 ]
```