# Capture part of node.js route

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/users/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);
app.get('/page/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);
app.get('/photo/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);
```

If I have the above 3 routes, how can I capture the first part so that the handler knows what is being requested? I'd like to have `users` or `page` or `photo` sent to the handler as part of the request object.

Ideally I'd like to avoid making this a single route with a regex as this is just a dumbed down example of my real use case.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482959/express-js-how-to-make-app-get-useridi-in-req-param) might lead you in the right direction.  You can also alternatively just use a regex and the matches will be captured in an array, like `req.params[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time due to your bindings, why not just pass the info in there?

```
app.get('/users/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler.bind(null, 'users'));

function ProfileHandler(pageRoot, req, res, next){
    switch (pageRoot){
        case 'users':

            break;
        case 'page':
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pattern you are using , ProfileHandler will be passed a req and res object. req has a url property that you can then split and switch-case:

```
app.get('/users/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);
app.get('/page/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);
app.get('/photo/:userId/profile', ProfileHandler);

function ProfileHandler(req,res){
   var reqType = req.url.split('/')[1];
   switch(reqType){
       case 'users':
      //DO SOMETHING COOL 
       break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add middleware that set that value on the request.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var reqType = req.url.split('/')[1];
    req.handlerTarget = reqType;
});

function ProfileHandler(req,res){
   switch(req.handlerTarget){
       case 'users':
      //DO SOMETHING COOL 
       break;
    }
}
```