# Add params on ExpressJS middlewares using regular expressions

Tags: regex, node.js, express

How can I pass a "path parameter" to a middleware when using regular expressions. Here is an example of what I need to do:

```
app.use(new RegExp('/aPath/(?!notThis){variable}'), myMiddleware);
```

So, in my middleware (that should not be executed for '/aPath/notThis') I need to get the parameter.

```
exports.myMiddleware = function (req, res, next){
  console.log(req.params.variable);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483381/2982518)

```
app.use(/:variable(?!notThis)/), myMiddleware);
```

Then in `myMiddleware` you can check the value of `variable` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass paramters to middleware by using the following syntax:

```
var myPath =  require('path')(variable);
app.use(myPath);
```

Then in your middleware:

```
module.exports = function (variable) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
```